# Como nomear cada linha de uma lista url

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler

Consigo nomear cada linha da lista de url, pra retornar apelido que eu dei pra ela?

Tipo assim o resultado foi esse:

```
 Prefeitura Municipal de Bocaiúva do Sul | PRONIM TB 518.01.07-013 |
 Prefeitura Municipal de Matinhos | PRONIM TB 518.01.04-000 |
 | PRONIM TB 518.01.07-012 |
 Prefeitura Municipal de Castanhal | PRONIM TB 518.01.07-012 |
```

Nesses casos eu sei qual site é porque o parametro no site esta ok

Mas tem casos como a penúltima linha que não tem no site e não tem de onde eu buscar, porém eu sei de onde é pois tenho o link do site.

Será que é possível setar um nome diferente para cada url 
como se fosse apelidar cada url e na hora de puxar pro arquivo trazer esse apelido?

o Codigo é esse:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const { get } = require('request');
const { writeFileSync } = require('fs');
const { promisify } = require('util');

// Transforma o "get" em uma função que retorna uma promessa
const promisedGET = promisify(get);

const visitar = async uri => {
const { statusCode, body } = await promisedGET({ uri, encoding: 'binary' });

// Retorna um erro caso o status seja diferente de 200
if (statusCode !== 200) throw new Error(body);

return { body };
}

const ler = async ({ body }) => {
const $ = cheerio.load(body);

const cliente = $('table.Class_Relatorio tr:nth-of-type(4) > td:nth-of- 
type(2)').text().trim();
const versao = $('table.Class_Relatorio tr:nth-of-type(1) > td:nth-of- 
type(1)').text().trim();

return { cliente, versao };
}

const executar = async urls => {
 // Faz requisições para todos os sites da lista
const paginas = await Promise.all(urls.map(url => visitar(url)));
// Lê as páginas retornadas e transforma em objetos
const linhas = await Promise.all(paginas.map(conteudo => ler(conteudo)));
// Transforma as linhas em uma string de conteúdo
const conteudo = linhas.map(({ cliente, versao }) => `${cliente} | ${versao} 
|`).join('\n');
 // grava o conteúdo no arquivo
 writeFileSync('versao.txt', conteudo);

 return conteudo;
 }

// Exemplo da chamada da função principal
(async () => {
// Inicia o timer
  console.time('Execução');

 try {
 await executar([

  ]);
  } catch (err) {
  console.log(err)
 }

 // Totaliza o tempo de execução
  console.timeEnd('Execução');
 })();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altere a função executar para receber um `array` de objetos ao invés de um `array` de `string` e repasse isso para a gravação da linha.

```
...
await executar([
  { assinatura: 'Bocaiúva do Sul', url: 'http://transparencia.bocaiuvadosul.pr.gov.br:9191/pronimtb/index.asp' },
  { assinatura: 'Matinhos', url: 'http://transparencia.matinhos.pr.gov.br/pronimtb/index.asp' },
  { assinatura: 'Rolândia', url: 'http://transparencia.rolandia.pr.gov.br/pronimtb/index.asp' },
  { assinatura: 'Castanhal', url: 'http://transparencia.castanhal.pa.gov.br/pronimtb/index.asp' },
]);
...
```

Depois a linha que mapeia as promessas de visitação de `url`:

```
const paginas = await Promise.all(urls.map(({ assinatura, url }) => visitar(assinatura, url)));
```

Altere a função `visitar` para retornar a assinatura no final:

```
...
const visitar = async (assinatura, uri) => {
...
return { assinatura, body };
...
```

Altere a função `ler` para retornar a assinatura no final:

```
...
const ler = async ({ assinatura, body }) => {
...
return { assinatura, cliente, versao };
...
```

E finalmente na linha que forma o que será gravado, adicione a assinatura:

```
...
const conteudo = linhas.map(({ assinatura, cliente, versao }) => `${assinatura} | ${cliente} | ${versao} |`).join('\n');
...
```

Comment: Eu só estava alterando no executar. Perfeito :) Obrigado